# how to check the list view items when we are using groups in list view  

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, listview

how to check the list view items when we are using list view group s...

I have list view in that i am using two groups ....

If i click on the list view first group item then  click on the list view second group item

I want to do something ...

for that i have done below ...

```
private void lstviewCatgeories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItems = lstviewCatgeories.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>();
    var passed = (selectedItems
        .Select(l => l.Group.Name)
        .Distinct()
        .Count() == 2 && selectedItems.Count() == 2
    );
    if (passed)
    {
        var categoryItem = selectedItems
            .Where(l => l.Group.Name.ToLower() == "catgories")
            .Single();
        var priceItem = selectedItems
            .Where(l => l.Group.Name.ToLower() == "pricesrangegroup")
            .Single();


    // do something


    }
}
```

but the control does not goes in to if condition even if i select the first item in group 1
and then i select the second item in second group

but it does not working ..

would any one pls help on this...

many thanks

**EDIT :** I am getting count 1 at this line    **lstviewCatgeories.SelectedItems**

would any one suggest any alternative solution for this.....

Comment: would any one pls help on this....

Comment: is my question is unclear would you pls inform to me ...

Comment: are you shore that after selecting second item `lstviewCatgeories.SelectedItems` collection has 2 items? multiselect property is enabled?

Comment: @Reniuz sorry it will shows count 1 at this line lstviewCatgeories.SelectedItems would pls tell any alternative solutions i have done this multiselect property is enabled..

Comment: you need to select items holding ctrl key. after you select second item if statement should pass.

Comment: if i select the cntrl key and select two items but it wil showing the count 1

Comment: select one item (event will rise and count = 1), press and hold <Ctrl> key and then select second item - event will rise and count will be = 2.

Comment: @reniuz  its working now but i dont want to use control key is there any option to do that with out using cntrl key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason of this problem is that you not selecting multiple items. You can select multiple items by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key or you need to think about enabling [CheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx) property to select multiple items with checkboxes.